# Redirecting Shutdown.exe errors to file

Tags: windows, command-line, shutdown

I'm creating a script to do rebooting of computers, and I need to report the success or failure of the shutdown.exe command as part of my script logging.  I'm having an issue with redirecting the output of failed shutdown.exe processes to a file.  Here is my command line:

```
shutdown.exe -r -t 50000 -m \\top34.top.local > c:\output.txt
```

When I run this, I see the following message on my screen: "top34.top.local: The entered computer name is not valid or remote shutdown is not supported on the target computer. Check the name and then try again or contact your system administrator.(53)", which is I am expecting, but c:\output.txt is blank - and does not contain this error.  My script needs to output this line to a text file for logging purposes.

I have also tried to wrap it around a CMD, like such:

```
cmd /c shutdown.exe -r -t 50000 -m \\top34.top.local > c:\output.txt
```

But this too produces no result.  I have also tried the double >> (append), but this makes no difference.

I've done a fair bit of investigation, and it appears that shutdown.exe will redirect output of successful commands to stdout, but not failed commands.  How can I get it to redirect both successful and failed commands to my file?

Running Windows 2012 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I get it (`shutdown`) to redirect both successful and failed commands to my file?

Use the following command:

```
shutdown.exe -r -t 50000 -m \\top34.top.local > c:\output.txt 2>&1
```

Note that the `2>&1` should be **after** the first `>` redirect.

---

> **Duplicating handles**
>
> The `&` redirection operator duplicates output or input from one
>   specified handle to another specified handle. For example, to send
>   `dir` output to File.txt and send the error output to `File.txt`, type:
>
> ```
> dir > c:\file.txt 2>&1
> ```

Source [Using command redirection operators](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: The "dir" command redirects as it should and as you pointed out, but the shutdown command does not. I get 0-byte files from using "shutdown.exe" in place of "dir". CMD: shutdown.exe -r -f -t 600 > out.txt 2>&1

Comment: Never mind, this was a total user error on my part.

Comment: I don't remember what this user error was that I somehow resolved because it is still happening now. 0-byte log files, even though the remote machine shuts down. I'm using -m {remotehostname}